# Elasticsearch and MongoDB: no river _meta document found after 5 attempts

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a MongoDB database named `news` to which I tried to index with ES.
Using these plugins:

**richardwilly98.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/2.0.9**
and **elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.5.0**

This is what happening when I tried to create the index. I have tried to delete the index and recreating it, without that helping.

`$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/news/_meta' -d @init.json`

**init.json**

```
{
"type": "mongodb",
"mongodb": {
    "db": "news",
    "collection": "entries"
},
"index": {
    "name": "news",
    "type": "entries"
}
}
```

**Here is a log**

```
update_mapping [mongodb] (dynamic)
MongoDB River Plugin - version[2.0.9] - hash[73ddea5] - time[2015-04-06T21:16:46Z]
setRiverStatus called with mongodb - RUNNING
river mongodb startup pending
Starting river mongodb
MongoDB options: secondaryreadpreference [false], drop_collection [false], 
include_collection [], throttlesize [5000], gridfs [false], filter [null], 
db [news], collection [entries], script [null], indexing to [news]/[entries]
MongoDB version - 3.0.2
update_mapping [mongodb] (dynamic)
[org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.CollectionSlurper] Cannot ..
  import collection entries into existing index
d with mongodb - INITIAL_IMPORT_FAILED
Started river mongodb
no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
no river _meta document found after 5 attempts
```

Any suggestions to what might be wrong?
I'm running **ES 1.5.2** and **MongoDB 3.0.2** on **OS X**.

Comment: What do you see when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_river/news/_search` ?

Comment: {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}

Comment: Ok, nothing got stored as a result of your curl. Can you try with `--data-binary @init.json` instead of `-d @init.json`

Comment: Tried `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_river/mongodb
=> {"acknowledged":true}%`. And `curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' --data-binary @init.json => 
{"_index":"_river","_type":"mongodb","_id":"_meta","_version":1,"created":true}%`

Comment: The result now is: {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}

Comment: then the type should be `mongodb` not `news` => `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_search`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77908/discussion-between-val-and-martins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [the mongodb river github pages](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb#mongodb-river-plugin-for-elasticsearch), it looks like the plugin is supported up until version 1.4.2, but not higher (i.e. you're running 1.5.2)

Also note that rivers have been deprecated in ES v1.5 and there's an [open issue](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/issues/505) in the mongodb river project on this very topic.

**UPDATE after chatting with @martins**

Finally, the issue was simply that the name of the created river was wrong (i.e. `news` instead of `mongodb`), the following command would properly create the mongodb river, which still works with ES 1.5.2 even though not it's officially tested.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d @init.json
```

Comment: the issue refer to says that the river will be supported / kept until 2,0

Comment: Yes, ES will support rivers until 2.0, but my comment was more about whether the mongodb plugin still supports it. Right now, it doesn't seem to work with ES 1.5.x.

Comment: Aha, I see. What's the current solution for having ES and MongoDB being friends these days?

Comment: Try to use ES 1.4.2 maybe?

Comment: Yes, the testmongo example at https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb#build-status still works.